# Sorting function not working with generic Angular Material Table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I created my own generic component with Material Table to use it in my application. So the problem is with sorting - it doesn't work at all. The arrow next to the column header shows but nothing happen. I found that it can be problem with `ngIf` over `<table` but.. I don't have it (only inside of the table but these are not the problem). Maybe someone can help me with that?

Component:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
@Input() data: any[] = [];
@Input() columns: GridColumn[] = [];
displayedColumns: string[] = [];
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

ngOnInit() {
for (const column of this.columns) {
  this.displayedColumns.push(column.id);
}

this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.data);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}

getValue(object: any, path: string) {
return getNestedValue(object, path);
}
```

And the template:

```
<table class="w-100" mat-table [dataSource]="data" matSort>
 <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">

  <ng-container *ngIf="!column.content" cdkColumnDef="{{column.id}}">
   <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{column.label | translate}}</th>
   <td cdk-cell class="position-relative" *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row[column.id]}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="column.content" cdkColumnDef="{{column.id}}">
   <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{column.label | translate}}</th>
   <td cdk-cell class="position-relative" *cdkCellDef="let row">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="column.content"
                  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{record: row, value: column.field ? getValue(row, column.field) : null}">
    </ng-container>
   </td>
  </ng-container>

 </ng-container>

 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

EDIT:
Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9cdqt

Comment: Can you please reproduce your issue in stackblitz?

Comment: @yurzui I just added stackblitz link to the question but it's not working correctly yet (I have some little problem with stackblitz configuration, probably in the module file), maybe you will display table faster than me

Comment: Done, problem is reproduced, stackblitz link in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that there is no reactive flow in your example.

You have no connection to `MatTableDataSource` since you passed plain array to `dataSource` input property instead.

A quick fix should be:

```
[dataSource]="dataSource"
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9cdqt-yg1tem?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sorting-example.html)**